# Is it possible to find the solution to a power series from knowing the coefficients and their sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have a sum of the form
$$I = \sum_{k=c}^{\infty} a_k$$
Where both $I$ and $a_k$ are known, is it in general possible to find a closed form solution for
$$\sum_{k=c}^{\infty} a_k z^k$$

Comment: Let's see: $\sum_{k \geq 1} 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$ and $\sum_{k \geq 1} 1/k^4 = \pi^4/90$.  Do $\sum_{k \geq 1} z^k/k^2$ and $\sum_{k \geq 1} z^k/k^4$ have a closed form?

Comment: Not unless you count the polylogarithm to be closed form.

Comment: That's why I gave the second example.  You can keep making up names for functions you don't already have a name for, but that seems to defeat the point of the vague term "closed form".